# How to make a timer that will work in a couple of months?

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, c++98

There is a task to set a timer that will work in a couple of months. I ran into a problem with `QTimer::start(int msec)` time is specified in int and also in milliseconds. It turns out I can specify 2147483647 milliseconds, which is a little less than a month. I used to use `crontab`, but I had to abandon it.

Code example:

```
uint sec_prediction, sec_now, answer;

QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
sec_now = now.toTime_t();
QLocale mylocale(QLocale::English);
qDebug() << mylocale.toString(now, "MMM d hh:mm:ss") << sec_now;

QDateTime payment = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
payment = payment.addMonths(3);
sec_prediction = payment.toTime_t();
qDebug() << mylocale.toString(payment, "MMM d hh:mm:ss") << sec_prediction;

answer = sec_prediction - sec_now;
qDebug() << answer << " - After this time, the timer should start. \n";

QTimer timer;
timer.setSingleShot(true);
connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processQueue()));
timer.start(answer * 1000);
```

Console output:

```
"Jan 7 00:42:38" 1673041358
"Apr 7 00:42:38" 1680817358
7776000  - After this time, the timer should start.

QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot have negative intervals
```

I am using Qt 4.8

Grateful for help

Comment: Make a daily or hourly (or some other smaller interval) timer and check to see if a couple of months has passed.

Comment: Set a timer to a task whose logic is IF final time > 20 days THEN call again in 20 days ELSE IF final time in future THEN set timer for final time ELSE do actual work.

Comment: Make sure your timer is based on wall clock time and not system time (as most UX timer libraries are). Otherwise, time stops as soon as the user's laptop shuts down. A lot of my team's timer libraries are system timers that fire hourly such that it checks the wall clock time to compare with scheduler timers.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using c++98 you can use [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv) (C library) which supports [timers](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/guide/utilities.html#timers)

```cpp
uv_timer_t timer_req; // Timers invoke the registered callback after a certain
                      // time has elapsed since the timer was started.

uv_timer_init(loop, &timer_req); // Docs show how to create an event loop

// This call is non blocking but YOU have to make 
// sure your program still runs after a month.
uv_timer_start(&timer_req, callback, 5000, 2000);
//  here put a month's worth of secs ^^    ^^ 
//           optionally set this to repeat ^^

// After waiting for "interval sesc" your callback runs
```

I see that Qt4.8 doesn't have the convenient `QTimer::CallOnTimeout` method, but it provides a `QTimer` class which is wired a bit [differently](https://dreamswork.github.io/qt4/classQTimer.html#a3b4fd7191bc2ebd5a19c74a1ebbe53eb):

```cpp
// Create a QTimer, connect its timeout() signal to the 
// appropriate slots, and call start(). From then on it 
// will emit the timeout() signal at constant intervals.

QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start(1000); // 1000 milliseconds timer.
```

---

Shameless plug of my [C++ chrono-scheduler library](https://github.com/picanumber/task_timetable). Using it would look like this:

```cpp
#include "scheduler.h"

{
    bool compensate = true; // a README explains
    unsigned nWorkers = 1;  // these values in the repo.

    // 1. Create a scheduler.
    ttt::CallScheduler plan(compensate, nWorkers);

    // 2. Add your task.
    auto myTask = []{
        // You may want to repeat in another month
        return ttt::Result::Finish; 
    };

    auto token = plan.add(
        myTask,   // User tasks are std::function<ttt::Result()>
        24h * 30, // Interval for execution or repetition
        false);   // Whether to immediately queue the task for execution

    // 3. Wait a month .... 
}
```

Essentially the scheduler has a pool of threads that:

1. Register tasks
2. Execute tasks at the specified intervals
3. Potentially re-register the tasks if they need re-running

This is the most general solution to the problem of adding ad-hoc as many tasks as you want, with millisecond (and even less) granularity without blocking the caller or the execution context. But the logic found within can be extracted and simplified for your case.